# There is a way to know how many partitions has a number?

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

The title says it all, there is a way to know how many partitions has a number?

With "a way" i mean if there is any formula or polynomials to provide the number of ways to "part" a number.

The question arose up after i answer the query "What are the partitions of 5?"
I found seven, in fact is seven, but i would appreciate a double check

Comment: There is efficient software for this, but as far as I know no closed-form analytic formula.  If you just want a check, then very simple functions calls will suffice.  In *Mathematica*:  `IntegerPartitions[5]` will list them all, and `Length[IntegerPartitions[5]]` will count them.

Comment: This is a complicated matter. https://uva.theopenscholar.com/files/ken-ono/files/097.pdf

Comment: Note that [stars and bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) can **not** be used here because Stars and Bars will overcount each non-negative integer solution to (for example) $x_1 + \cdots + x_5 = 5$ in a **variable** # of ways.  For example, re wlpj2011's answer, (4 + 1) will appear as ($5 \times 4 = 20$) different Stars and Bars solutions, while ($1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$) will appear only once.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)) which allows you to calculate exactly how many integer partitions there are of a given integer by calculating the coefficients of the $n^\textrm{th}$ term of the series
$$(1+x+x^2+\cdots)(1+x^2+x^4 + \cdots)(1+x^3+x^6+\cdots)\cdots.$$ As you found, there are $7$ partitions of $5$ which are the following.

\begin{align}
5&=5 \\
5&=4+1 \\
5&=3+1+1 \\
5&=2+1+1+1 \\
5&=1+1+1+1+1 \\
5&=2+3 \\
5&=2+2+1
\end{align}

There isn't a known way to write these coefficients as a polynomial or anything, but we do know that it grows like $\frac{1}{4n\sqrt{3}}e^{\pi \sqrt{2n/3}}$ as $n \to \infty$. So we can figure out approximately how many integer partitions there are for large $n$.